# How to write data tables in postgresql from Microsoft sql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am learning C# programing from ScottLilly.com and I have a little problem.
In this chapter https://www.scottlilly.com/learn-c-by-building-a-simple-rpg-index/lesson-22-2-creating-database-tables-from-classes/ and mayb in the future chapter he use Microsoft SQL like database.
I cannot instal this so I instaled Postgresql but after that I realise that he doesn't show me how to use it.
Can someone give me some help to understand how to modify his code? and where to use it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question. "How do I use software x" is overly broad.

Comment: You could use the free edition of SQL Server - https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express. Does that help?